# search in array for string match

Tags: javascript, regex

**What i have**

```
var sentence = 'My country is India';
var array = ['Intel,' 'Goa', 'Green Day', 'India', 'Ice', 'India'];
```

**Result i need**

```
  index = array.indexOf(sentence); // it should return 3
```

And this is what i tried it works but its very slow and freezes and stop working when use big data

```
words = sentence.split(' ');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    w = words[i];
    a = array.indexOf(w);
    console.log(a);
}
```

**Update** : i tried below solutions but still stop working i am working on google audio to speech so its run continually some one speeak so sentence array triggers again and again i think this is why its freezing after some point

**Update 2:** In above example i search for single word i.e. "India" but what if i its more than one word like if its a person name like "Neil Armstrong" then split method will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array#indexOf` is an `O(n)` operation - the interpreter has to iterate through the whole array, worst-case, to see if there's a match or not. When done in a loop, this increases the computational complexity to `O(n ^ 2)`, which will be slow.

You can use a Set instead - `Set#has` has a complexity of `O(1)` (reducing the overall complexity to `O(n))`:

```js
var sentence = 'My country is India';
var array = ['Intel', 'Goa', 'Green Day', 'India', 'Ice'];

const words = new Set(sentence.split(' '));
console.log(
  array.findIndex(word => words.has(word))
);
```

Or an object (object key lookup is `O(1)` too):

```js
var sentence = 'My country is India';
var array = ['Intel', 'Goa', 'Green Day', 'India', 'Ice'];

const words = Object.fromEntries(
  sentence.split(' ').map(key => [key])
);
console.log(
  array.findIndex(word => words.hasOwnProperty(word))
);
```

See how you can also use `findIndex` to make the code much more concise.

If the item you're hoping to match is composed of two words, also match every occurrence of 2 words next to each other:

```js
var sentence = 'My country is Green Day';
var array = ['Intel', 'Goa', 'Green Day', 'India', 'Ice'];

const words = new Set(sentence.split(' '));
const pattern = /(?=(\S+ \S+))/g;
while (true) {
  const match = pattern.exec(sentence);
  if (!match) {
    break;
  }
  words.add(match[1]);
  pattern.lastIndex++;
}
console.log(
  array.findIndex(word => words.has(word))
);
```

For a more general solution, you can check the input array to identify which number of words you need to collect, then for each number, iterate over the sentence words to add them to a Set:

```js
var sentence = 'My country is Green Day';
var array = ['Intel', 'Goa', 'Green Day', 'India', 'Ice'];

const combinationsNeeded = new Set();
for (const substr of array) {
  combinationsNeeded.add(substr.split(' ').length);
}
const wordsSet = new Set();
const sentenceWords = sentence.split(' ');
for (const comb of combinationsNeeded) {
  let endIndex = comb;
  for (let i = 0; i + comb <= sentenceWords.length; i++) {
    // uncomment the below to see all the words wordsSet gets
    // console.log(sentenceWords.slice(i, i + comb).join(' '));
    wordsSet.add(sentenceWords.slice(i, i + comb).join(' '));
  }
}

console.log(
  array.findIndex(substr => wordsSet.has(substr))
);
```

Comment: hi your solution working  for single word  how can i work for two word for example in my sentance i have a word ''Kurt Cobain" then it will not match bcoz its not  one word

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and expected output from that? You could make the Set composed of 2 words instead of 1, but I'm not certain what you're looking for there

Comment: but its not linted to 2 word or 3

Answer (score 0):

```
const sentence = 'My country is India';
const array = ['Intel', 'Goa', 'Green Day', 'India', 'Ice', 'India'];
const my_vals =  array.map((val, inx)=> sentence
                     .match(val)? inx : -1)
                     .filter(x => x>-1);
```

this will return an array with all the matching indexes.

```
[3, 5]
```